# sharepoint 2013 - Can we change elements around text from the ribbon?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

Within SharePoint 2013, on a publishing page, can I select and change the following text with a click of button from the ribbon...

Change:

```
<p>this should be my title</p>
```

...to...

```
<h2>this should be my title</h2>
```

Or do I have to go into HTML mode to make this change?

Comment: Have you checked this article? http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mvpawardprogram/archive/2011/05/16/mvps-for-sharepoint-2010-modifying-ribbon-fonts-and-styles-for-publishing-page-html-field-controls.aspx

Comment: Thanks, but that looks like its 2010 related...and it doesn't talk about switching elements.

Answer (score 0):

The approach remains the same and you can achieve it by adding/modifying the css classes using SPD

Detailed walkthrough here:
http://knowledge.zomers.eu/SharePoint/Pages/How-to-add-custom-styles-to-the-ribbon-in-SharePoint-2013.aspx

Comment: I don't want to add classes, that would be a mess.  I already have specific elements dedicated towards a curtain look and feel.  To mix in classes on top of that structure would be a nightmare for 1000's of pages.  I simply want to change elements.

Answer (score 0):

If you set AllowStyles to "true" as  an attribute on Rich Text Editors within your custom page layouts (or master template), you will then enable elements to be switched by picking styles of the ribbon for editor content.  This solves my issue.

"True" may be the default setting that displays when you get your text editor snippet from SharePoint in the browser....but I think I had set it to false previously and just totally forgot that I did that a while ago.  Now its back to True.

Thanks